# Go to anchor and scroll using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not really an JQuery and Javascript mogul. Hence, I'm facing an issue.

I'd like to move the page to a specific anchor as long as it has been loaded. The effect must seemless to the users.

I made it using this line of code:

```
location.hash = "story_section";
```

But, there is a problem: at the top of the page there is a fixed menu. Hence, the page did not lands in the proper position.

So, how could I roll the page some pixels from top?

I'm able to roll using JQuery, but only with animation:

```
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+secao).offset().top-altura}, 700);
```

Could you shed a light on this issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `scrollTop()` method:

```
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
    menuHeight = $('menu-selector').height();
$(window).scrollTop(currentScroll - menuHeight);
```